# The google map zoom and marker are not working

Tags: maps, zooming, marker

I don't know why the marker and zoom is not working and here is the code:

```
     function initialize() {
        if (document.getElementById("themap") != null) {
           $.post("http://localhost/projects/php/invoice/getmapinfo.php", {
              postalcode: $("#postalcode").html()
           },
             function(data, status) {
                if (data == "-1" || data == "-2" || data == "-3") {
                } else {
                   var apos     = data.split(',');
                   var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(apos[0]),  parseFloat(apos[1]));
                   var mapProp  = {
                       center:myCenter,
                       zoom:10,
                       mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   };

                   var map    = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("themap"),mapProp);
                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position:myCenter,
                   });

                   marker.setMap(map);
                }
             }
           );
        }
     }

     $(document).ready(
        function() {
           $(document).ajaxStop(
              function(){
                 initialize();
              }
           );
```

The map will show up but its is static.  Do I need to get a key or not because it is run on my internal web server for me only or am I missing a step.

Thanks if you can help.